# How do you prevent friending activity from showing up Facebook timeline?

Tags: facebook, privacy, facebook-timeline

I can't figure out how to do this, and the question isn't answered.

Comment: Which question are you taking about?

Answer (score 6):

Hover mouse over friending activity to see the small 'x'. Click on it to view the options seen in the image. Now to hide a single activity choose the first option - **Hide this recent activity story from Timeline** - or to hide all friending activity hit the second option - **Hide Similar Activity from Timeline**.

[image]

If you simply want to hide the activity from your friends, while keeping it visible to yourself, do what the first comment instructed. Go to https://facebook.com/friends. Change friends privacy setting to "**Only Me**".

[image]